# Take long second loading new simple scene in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a simple **2D game** in `Unity5` .

When i try load new scene its take 5 ~ 10 second maybe longer !

I'm developing it for `android` and when i run game inside `unity` or install `APK` on real device it not different .

I used this code for changing Levels or Scenes

```
Application.LoadLevel(level String name or Level int number);
```

I test it with a blank **scene that have only Text in UI** and it takes 5 ~ 10 second too !

I think this problem not relate to my sprites or scene size . its a unity or coding problem

pls help

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search more about this question and i found many **repetitive** in many forums  **but** really no solution or good answer i found .

After 1 hour struggled with this problem i founded cause.

I thought `Click Listener Method` of `UI Buttons` in `Unity` must be check in every frame but this was mistake .

Since in my project loading new scene happen when button clicked problem originate from here !

I got moved

`Button.onClick.AddListener(()=>{});`

From `Update()` to `Start()` method .

And simply problem solved .

If I'm not mistaken  `AddListener()` method run each frame like `Update()` method i not need write it on `Update()`.

I hope this question and this answer be helpful for anybody have problem like this :)

Thanks.

Comment: cool! Just realized that AddListener is more like setting up a trigger for the button and doing it one time should suffice!! I was hogging with LoadAsync for a long time! thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you shouldnt use application.loadlevel in unity5
you should instead do

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

and then do

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(NAME);
```

to load the scene

you can find the refrence for this at: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html
i hope this helped you.

Comment: I tested it right now . but problem not solved and new level coming up takes same long